# How do you build a bookcase around an outside or convex corner?

Tags: woodworking, wooden-furniture, built-ins

How do you build a bookcase around an outside or convex corner?

Comment: It might be useful to have a bit more detail in the question body.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to work out how to handle the outside corner for a built-in bookcase. One concept that I have used follows this plan:

[image]

The spacing of the knickknack shelves does not necessarily need to follow that of the book shelves.

This picture will help you visualize how it can end up looking.

[image]